# How do I debug services in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

The project I have been testing and debugging has been presenting some challenges. Stepping through the code in debug mode, I came across some calls to services.  This is something new to me.  After some investigation, I found that these classes are in the WCF world.  The exception that was thrown gave me a clue to what I am missing:

{"There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:52674/Services/InboundVendorServices.asmx that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 
See InnerException, if present, for more details."}

Clearly I needed to have localhost running locally.  I set up the localhost to run locally but I had the same error when I was debugging the code in visual studio.  In the solution explorer, I found the services:

[image]

I also noticed that if I right-click on these services, I am able to display their functionality in a browser.

[image]

At this point, I can test the operation of some function call through a form after clicking on that function name.

But how do I actually set up my system to run this in Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: What is the "this" in your question?